# Facebook Gameroom top bar not changing when debugging Unity game

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity3D and I'm now testing the recently added Facebook build target. When launching the game in the Gameroom client (for example by clicking '`Build And Run`' in Unity3D) I observed that the top bar (the one at the top of the Gameroom window) does NOT change at all and clicking on any buttons (for example my Facebook profile icon) opens a popup that appears below the game viewport.

I suppose this is only happening because the game is being executed is some kind of debug mode and that once the game will be published and downloaded directly from the client this issue will go away.

So the specific question is: is this behavior to be expected? Is it normal that launching from Unity3D with 'Build And Run' messes up the Gameroom top bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on the Unity forums and received an answer from one of the Unity employees. He contacted the Facebook devs and they said this is a known issue that will be fixed soon.

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/facebook-gameroom-gameroom-client-top-bar-not-updating.451786/